# WKWebView analog of service worker

Tags: ios, caching, service-worker, wkwebview, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to implement part of app with `PWA` approach, that works fine on `Android`, but not for `iOS`. We need to have

- offline content availability
- option to update content dynamically (like special offers or so). With service worker we show prompt to update web content.

As were mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673399/service-workers-unavailable-in-wkwebview-in-ios-11-3) service workers are not supported within `WKWebView` (or `UIWebView`). So is there analog or alternative solution like smart cache control?

Seems like it is possible to store some web content from app and be able to update it if something changes. May there is already a `framework/library/approach` for that purpose?

**EDIT**
[Service Workers unavailable in WKWebView in iOS 11.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673399/service-workers-unavailable-in-wkwebview-in-ios-11-3) - this question explains the status of ServiceWorkers in WKWebView, but no alternative is given. I would like to discuss any alternative solutions.

One thing I discovered is https://github.com/xtools-at/iOS-PWA-Wrapper. It looks like working based on AppCache, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache#Browser_compatibility says it is deprecated and adviced to use SW instead (which is not an option for PWA).

Comment: How about, trying the solutions listed in this [SO post (Service workers and iOS / Safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895387/service-workers-and-ios-safari)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 Thanks for reply, the link you gave tells it works on Safari (same in the link I posted above). But I didn't find any solution for WebView so far.

Comment: See here for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673399/service-workers-unavailable-in-wkwebview-in-ios-11-3/64155509#64155509

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So before WKWebView get service-workers to work, you can use AppCache (not yet fully deprecated).
You can use [this](https://github.com/xtools-at/iOS-PWA-Wrapper) and take a look at source page at https://leasingrechnen.at
What they do? In case if there is no service worker in browser, they load iframe that points to a page with `manifest.appcache` file implemented, so the page is cached.

Comment: As of iOS 15 AppCache is disabled for WKWebView. See: https://bugs.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=426150&action=diff