# WKWebview Service Workers

Tags: ios, service, safari, webkit, wkwebview

How can I enable Service Workers for WKWebview, I heard that they are working only in Safari? Are there any workarounds? I heard that in iOS 14 the Service Workers would be available again on WKWebviews, is this true?

I saw this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49673400/11999318

But adding `com.apple.developer.WebKit.ServiceWorkers` in `.entitlements` works only on simulator. Currently this will only work in the iOS Simulator, until such time as Apple update the Apple Developer Portal.

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Service Workers do not exist in WKWebView.

Comment: As of iOS 15, Service Workers work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64155509/841052, https://stackoverflow.com/q/70772419/841052