# Alternative for service-worker (background request) in iOS WKWebView < 14

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, wkwebview, background-sync

Since Service-workers are not supported in WkWebView in iOS < 14,

**Sources:**

1. http://openradar.appspot.com/51092505
2. https://webkit.org/blog/8090/workers-at-your-service/
3. [Service workers unavailable in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673399/service-workers-unavailable-in-wkwebview-in-ios-11-3#comment112961337_49673400)

is there any alternative to implement background request functionality with javascript that works in iOS WkWebView < 14 ?